# Laravel save a copy of the email on storage

Tags: email, laravel, output

I'm sending emails in Laravel with mandrill but I also want to save a copy of the email on the storage also (like mailoutput but in my own log folder)

Do you have any idea how to do that?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Though you can log mails in Laravel, it seems that emails will not actually be sent at the same time.

A simple solution would be to log emails yourself:

Find where you send emails and add customized logging statements.

```
Mail::send('emails.welcome', array('key' => 'value'), function($message)
{
    $message->to('foo@example.com', 'John Smith')->subject('Welcome!');
    Log::info('You email content and receivers here');
});
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer! I want to save the html output with view render but I have en error because of the embeded images... (Undefined variable). I need to find another solution